# How to get the partial derivative of probability to input in pyTorch?

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network, gradient, gradient-descent

I want to generate attack samples via the following steps:

1. Find a pre-trained CNN classification model, whose input is X and output is P(y|X), and the most possible result of X is y.
2. I want to input X' and get y_fool, where X' is not far away from X and y_fool is not equal to y
3. The steps for getting X' is:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbHZv.png)
4. How can I get the partial derivative described in the image?

Here is my code but I got None: (The model is Vgg16)

```
x = torch.autograd.Variable(image, requires_grad=True)
output = model(image)
prob = nn.functional.softmax(output[0], dim=0)
    
prob.backward(torch.ones(prob.size()))
print(x.grad)
```

How should I modify my codes? Could someone help me? I would be absolutely grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, the point is to backpropagate a "false" example through the network, in other words you need to maximize one particular coordinate of your output which does not correspond to the actual label of `x`.

Let's say for example that your model outputs `N`-dimensional vectors, that `x` label should be `[1, 0, 0, ...]` and that we will try to make the model actually predict `[0, 1, 0, 0, ...]` (so `y_fool` actually has its second coordinate set to 1, instead of the first one).

Quick note on the side : `Variable` is deprecated, just set the `requires_grad` flag to `True`. So you get :

```
x = torch.tensor(image, requires_grad=True)
output = model(x)
# If the model is well trained, prob_vector[1] should be almost 0 at the beginning
prob_vector = nn.functional.softmax(output, dim=0)
# We want to fool the model and maximize this coordinate instead of prob_vector[0]
fool_prob = prob_vector[1]
# fool_prob is a scalar tensor, so we can backward it easy
fool_prob.backward()
# and you should have your gradients : 
print(x.grad)
```

After that, if you want to use an `optimizer` in your loop to modify `x`, remember that pytorch `optimizer.step` method tries to minimize the loss, whereas you want to maximize it. So either you use a negative learning rate or you change the backprop sign :

```
# Maximizing a scalar is minimizing its opposite
(-fool_prob).backward()
```